# How to subtract two datetime variable in django

Tags: django

```
now = datetime.today()

for item in itemList:
    elapsed = item.endDate
    if elapsed - now > 1:
        item.overdue = 1
    elif now - now > 3:
        item.banned = 1
```

can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Answer (score 1):

```
now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

for item in itemList:
    elapsed = now - item.endDate               
    bannedDiff = now - item.endDate
    if elapsed > timedelta(days=-1):
        item.overdue = 1
    elif bannedDiff > timedelta(days=-6):
        item.banned = 1
```

Figured it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a timezone aware "now" from [`django.utils.timezone`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#concepts).

```
from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.now()
```

> When time zone support is enabled (USE_TZ=True), Django uses
>   time-zone-aware datetime objects. If your code creates datetime
>   objects, they should be aware too.

But then do also confirm you are comparing `dates` as you seem to intend, as a `date` does not have tzinfo whereas `datetime` does: